# Python unit test that nothing was executed

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest, python-mock

In a method that looks like:

```
def my_method(p):
    if p == 5:
        return
    elif p == 6:
        do_something()
        return
    else:
        do_something_different()
        return
```

How do I use Python unit test to check that when I call `my_method(5)` nothing extra is executed or changed outside my_method? I know that I can mock `do_something` and `do_something_different` and use `assert_not_called` but, is there a way to do it that only considers the `if p == 5:` part?

Comment: How could you ever tell without checking all memory that the method could potentially affect? If you're testing it as a black box, you can't. If you have a white box, use your common sense.

Comment: If you restrict the question to something more sensible, like `do*()` all affect some limited portion of the state, you can verify that that portion does not change. But "no side effects at all" is a tall order to prove satisfactorily.

Comment: Any chance that you actually want to test if _everything_ got executed? In that case take a look at [`coverage`](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/6.2/). In any case: With code-coverage you'll see what wasn't executed.

Comment: There's a joke in the Haskell community that a function that returns an `IO` value could do anything, including launch nuclear missiles. Here you have a function which is called only for its side effect; there are too many things that `my_method` could leave undone to check for all of them.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55422951/unit-testing-a-method-that-update-only-some-properties

Answer (score 1):

> "*nothing extra is executed ..*"

Using [`coverage`](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/6.2/) you can see what has been executed and therefore also see what has *not* been executed.

You'll get a report and see what your tests didn't cover. For example:

```
$ coverage report -m
Name                      Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
-------------------------------------------------------
my_program.py                20      4    80%   33-35, 39
my_other_module.py           56      6    89%   17-23
-------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                        76     10    87%
```

It also supports the generation of HTML files so you get a visualization too if needed. In the docs find [this example](https://nedbatchelder.com/files/sample_coverage_html/d_7b071bdc2a35fa80_backward_py.html).

If you run `my_method(5)`, `coverage` will therefore show you what parts of your program weren't executed.

> "*.. or changed outside my_method*"

I have never done something like this and I am not sure if it's possible in a sensible way but I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61657432/python-tracemallocs-compare-to-function-delivers-always-statisticdiff-objec) which refers to [`tracemalloc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tracemalloc.html). Maybe this module can help you.